# How to Convert String to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string `20160522115200` and need to convert into `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format.

```
Ex: 2016-05-22 11:52:00  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski No it's not - what you linked deals with Objective-c not Swift and also deals with converting NSDate to NSString, not the other way around.

Comment: OK, so the OP needs to Google `swift Convert String to NSDate` which takes about 3 seconds and returns 19,600 results.

Comment: Converting from Obj-C to Swift (same API) is so extremely hard... oh well...

Answer (score 1):

Try below line of code:

```
 NSString * str = @"20160522115200";
 NSDateFormatter * d1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 d1.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMddhhmmss";
 NSDate * date = [d1 dateFromString: str];
 d1.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
 str = [d1 stringFromDate: date];
```

Comment: Is this Swift or Objective-c?

Comment: I'm a big fan of Objective-c :) Although this question is specifically a swift question as denoted by OP's tags.

Comment: Redaction, upon reviewing the edit history of the post, it appears OP did not specify Swift or Objective-c and another SO users edited in the "swift" tag which is sloppy in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift You will need to do the following:

Format the current Date String :

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddhhmmss"
let date = formatter.dateFromString("20160522115200")
```

Convert the new String to your new format :

```
let formatterToNewDate = NSDateFormatter()
formatterToNewDate.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let myNewDate = formatterToNewDate.stringFromDate(date!)
```